# If new row exist than display number of new rows

Tags: php, count, record, newrow

I have a problem and i dont know how to do this. I tryed to find information about that maybe 2-3 hours.

**I have this code:**

```
<?php
$stmt = $db->query("select count(id) from $medis order by zinutes")->fetchColumn();
echo $stmt;
?>
```

**Explanation:**

At the moment, in "zinutes" row, there is 10 records, and this code displays number "10".

**Question:**

If i am inserting new record, i need to display another number with new record inserted. How can i do this properply? And is this even possible without jquery? I am not good at php.

Thanks for any answers!

Comment: Sorry, but what? If you insert another row, you'll properly get 11 - what exactly is your question? How do you define a "new row"?

Comment: Using Jquery, `var count = 10 + 1;`

Comment: Sorry, maybe i made a mistake in my question. I mean, that this query displays me total records in "zinutes" row as number, and if i am inserting two or more new records in "zinutes" row, than i should get for example: (10) (2). And when i will click on (2), than (2) should become (0). I mean that, if in "zinutes" row is new record, than display number of new records and if i will click for example on (2), than (2) should dissapear :|. Sorry for bad english.

Comment: In your query you just return the number of records. This is in no way related to the number you want. The 10 you get is because you have 10 records. If you remove the first record, this query will return 9, even though record 10 still exists.

Comment: I know i wrote that in my main question. But how can i do that with another query? Or this is not possible? :|